# Testing a web-service from an Inetrnet browser

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a C# program which connects to a web service on a remote server. It has been working fine until now but recently the server changed and now when my program sends a request I get back a timeout error.

The customer says that when he tests a similar call with SOAP UI he gets a reply.

My question is: is there a way to do test calls to a web-service using Internet Explorer?

the SOAP envelope for the server looks something like this:

```
POST /SomeWS/Authorization/Login.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: SomeHostName
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.company.com/HQLWebServices/UserLogin"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UserLogin xmlns="http://www.company.com/HQLWebServices">
      <in_UserName>string</in_UserName>
      <in_Password>string</in_Password>
    </UserLogin>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I use this to post a request through IE? Can it be done?

Comment: Not easily.  Why not use SOAP UI yourself to test the actual call?  Or use Postman with Chrome (see http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/)

Comment: According to this MSDN article it shouldn't be too hard. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719483(v=vs.71).aspx


Just type the WS address, Method name and parameters.


But when I do it, like so:



http://SomehostName/SomeWS/Autorization/Login.asmx/UserLogin?in_UserName=TheUserName

I get HTTP error 500 "The website cannot display the page".